# Python, Track Daily Record Count

Tags: python-2.7

I've got a script that runs on a cronjob every hour doing some web scraping. At the end of each run I'll have returned a # of records found. Each run will have different values.

What's the most elegant solution to tracking these over the long term? I'd want to sum these up at the end of each day.

Is a CSV the most simple method? If so, what's the best way of doing that?

The challenge I was running into was opening, reading and then writing to the same csv file.

Is there a package that does this already?

Thanks

Comment: Consider `sqlite` if you do not want to deal with file-level semantics.

Comment: any good tutorials for a beginner you'd recommend?